# Location of Keyboard Icons?

Tags: keyboard, macos, icon, input-source

I probably should elaborate. I'm looking for the icons for the keyboards (the flags and the cutout-of-white icons used for Japanese/Chinese/that one used for custom inputs). I did some poking around and couldn't find them. If you find them please post an answer. I really need these for something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag icons are located in the file */System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat*. The *.dat* file can be opened/read with the [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) app.

The *.dat* file is a flag "database". To access the single flags in GraphicConverter use the pages drop-down menu at the bottom right of the main window.

---

Several input method icons (e.g. PNGs, TIFFs) can be found at */System/Library/Input Methods/Input_method.app/Contents/Resources/...* with *Input_method.app* one of the various IM.apps in */System/Library/Input Methods*.

The Custom Input icon may be this one: */System/Library/Input Methods/PluginIM.app/Contents/Resources/Custom.tiff*.

Comment: Cool! May I ask either how you found it or how you knew where it is? Also, do you know how I could edit/replace the icons?

Comment: I opened the .dat file and it's just one (Czech - QWERTY) flag. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I looked through all of them and I can't find the Custom Input icon. Is it in a different file? Sorry if I'm pestering you, btw. :)

Comment: Like a lowercase `c` in a rounded square (similarly to the icons that aren't flags).

Comment: Yes. For me it's black on white but I'm using the dark theme.

Comment: What kind of format is the .dat file?