# Where do the language indicator icons live in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, mojave, language

Where do the language indicator icons live in OSX?

[image]

[image]

I'm on OSX Catalina but if different on Mojave, would appreciate where it is on Mojave too.

I want to write a program that shows that icon in a different context.

Comment: For an old answer, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234373/location-of-keyboard-icons

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke! I verified this continues to be true in OSX Catalina 10.15.6 so self-marked as duplicate.